# Recontruct a line of code in PHP without directly touching the core file itself

Tags: php, timthumb

I am using a little PHP script on my site called timthumb.php. The script crops and resizes images on the fly and creates a folder called `cache` in the same location as the script where it stores the new images.

Is it possible somehow in PHP to write a line of code in another file which can replace the line of code in timthumb.php where the 'cache' folder location is defined?

I've had a look in timthumb.php and on line 40 is the following:

```
if(! defined('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY')) define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', './cache');
```

I've experimented with changing the last part `./cache` to for example `../../../uploads` and this works fine. My only reservation with doing this is it'll be lost if/when timthumb.php is next updated, so I wondering if there might be another solution.

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I am new to PHP.

Comment: offtopic, but just a heads up: timthunb has a [vulnerability](http://markmaunder.com/2011/08/19/wordpress-security-please-delete-old-themes-and-plugins/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the script that loads `timthumb.php` add the following line before the call to `include`.

```
define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', './cache')
```

and change `./cache` to wherever you want your cache to be.

**Explanation:**
The script checks if the constant `FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY` was defined by you, if not it will use the default value (`./cache`).

Comment: You sir are a star. Thanks so much, that works perfectly!